# Problems with the XML format

Tags: xml, jaxb

I'm creating a wesite which communicates with the server through xml's. In my localhost everything works perfectly fine. Although when upload my website to the server instead of this xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <quser xmlns="http://www..." xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">              
   <username>name</username>
</quser>
```

I;m taking this one:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   < :quser xmlns: ="http://www2...." xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
  < :username>readered</ :username>
  <:quser>
```

I declare in my model the following package-info.class

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
  namespace="http://www..",
  elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
  xmlns = { 
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix=" ", namespaceURI="http://www.."),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix="atom" ,namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom")
   }
 )

  package model;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

As i told you in my localhost is working perfectly fine but in the server even if i change the prefix(just for testing i set it prefix="xs") doesn't adopt the changes. Only in my localhost adopt it. Its very wired if you think that the changes i made in my loclhost,when i debug and upload the code on the server should contain them.

Moreover, i realise that i forgot some JAXB libraries into the WEB-INF. Just for testing i insert my libs and into the main program library. Then i took and in my localhost the same xml format as in the server. So i decide to delete these libraries from both places. After this in my localhost everything works again but in the server not. Please if anyone face or knows something regard to this issue to give me some instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the space in the prefix declaration:

This

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix="", namespaceURI="http://www..ckp"),
```

Instead of

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix=" ", namespaceURI="http://www..ckp"),
```

Comment: @NickRobertson - Which server and version are you using?

Comment: apache tomcat 7 on my localhost,apache tomcat 6 on the server

Comment: Are they running Java SE 6 or later?  Are you able to deploy without including the JAXB libraries in your WAR/EAR?

Comment: Yes.Its wired because i have and other package and i implement the same process on them and its working there.But i don't know why it doesn't work know.Is there any alternative choice to create the same XML format? I mean instead of writing this: @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix="", namespaceURI="http://www..ckp"), to the package-info.java to declare it anywhere else?

Comment: @NickRobertson - The following may help: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html